# Yii Condition in CGridView Column

Tags: yii, cgridview

I want to add a condition in a column of CGridView

I want to add a function in which the column is visible depending on a condition.

If status is equal to 10 column display. If not equal to 10, not shown

Hi, thanks for your answer. Im try your solution but doesn't work.

The column is part of a table from a query in which two tables are used: files and user. The query displays a user uploaded files, what I want is that the column that says looks "View" when the file status is 10

I try this

```
array(
'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/img/view.png',
'header'=>'View', 
'class'=>'CLinkColumn',
                                                                                                  'linkHtmlOptions'=>array('title'=>'View'),
'visible'=> '$data->status == 10'
)
```

And This

```
array(
'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/img/view.png',
'header'=>'View', 
'class'=>'CLinkColumn',
                                                                                                  'linkHtmlOptions'=>array('title'=>'View'),
'visible'=> '$data->status == 10?True:False'
)
```

Doesnt work!. PLease Help

Comment: I used `$data->status == ...` many times and it works for me. It's the correct syntax. Probably the problem is something else. Can you post whole of view file?

Comment: What you mean "Doesnt work"? The column shown in every row?(your condition ignored?)

Answer (score 0):

Test functions. For example:

```
<?php
    function isVisible($status){
            if($status == 10) return true;
            else return false;
    }
?> 
    // CGridView
    array(
    'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/img/view.png',
    'header'=>'View', 
    'class'=>'CLinkColumn',                                                                                                 'linkHtmlOptions'=>array('title'=>'View'),

    'visible'=> 'isVisible($data->status)'
    )
```

Comment: Hi, Im use a function. In the column i'm call function, and works fine only for one row. If the result its more than 1 show me that error
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare isVisible() (previously declared in...

Comment: Try this:
'columns'=>array(
   'name_column'=>array('value' => 'isVisible($data->status)' ... //add a header and name